# Force Firefox bookmarks to load in new tab

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, toolbar

So the problem is that i would prefer my bookmarks in the bookmarks toolbar to load into a new tab. But I can't seem to locate that option anywhere. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Middle-click or control-click on the bookmarks to open them in a new tab.

Or, if you really want a normal click to open bookmarks in a new tab, you can install the [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122) extension and enable this. Here's how:

1. Open the Tab Mix Plus Options window
2. Click on the *Events* icon
3. Click on the *Tab Opening* tab
4. In the *Open tabs from:* section, enable *Bookmarks*

Comment: +1: Awesome extension.  I was unaware this existed.

Comment: I had no idea that middle click did anything. And I use Firefox every single day. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: +1 for tab mix plus extension mention. I've used it for a while, and I wouldn't be without it now.

Answer (score 0):

Not serious answer: Firefox is open source change how it opens in the code and recompile it.

Serious answer: Middle clicking or control-clicking a bookmark or link will open it in a new tab.  Other then that I do not believe there is a way to do it